# How do I make SmtpClient connect to the server but not send any messages?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509certificate, smtpclient

I need to programmatically check the expiration date of the SMTP server SSL certificate. The following approach works:

- call `SmtpClient.Send()`
- access `SmtpClient.ServicePoint.Certificate`

The only problem is that it causes an email being sent and this is not very convenient - those messages will have to be dealt with (such as for example being deleted using a mail routing rule).

Can I somehow cause `SmtpClient` to establish connection (and so fetch the server side certificate) but not send any messages?

Comment: you can use SslStream instead of SmtpClient

Comment: @NoamWies: I tried `SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient()` and got *The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.* which I guess is because the server expects that TLS is enabled in the middle of SMTP session.